# Displaying an optional input field triggered by a radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, radio-button, hidden-field

As you can see here, I have a bulleted list. The last option on that list is "Other". When Other is selected, I want the "If Other, please describe here:" element and respective input box to be displayed. If "Other" is not selected, then I'd like to keep it hidden.

Is this possible?

```
<div class="section section_required">
    <asp:Label ID="PleaseSelect" runat="server" 
        Text="Please select the type of content:"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Width="675px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="content1">Alumni Achievement/ Alumni Profile</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="content2">List of Training Sites or Locations our Graduates are working</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="content3">Employer/ Advisory Board Testimonials</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content4">Appointments to Professional Organizations and Boards</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content5">Awards and Recognition</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content6">Bios</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content7">White Papers/ Articles/ Books Published</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content8">Student Acheivements/ Success Stories</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content9">Guest Speaker/ Lecture Series</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content10">Events/ Announcements</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content11">Photo/ Video of Past Events</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Content12">Other:</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:Label ID="otherLabel" runat="server" 
        Text="If Other, please describe here: "></asp:Label>
    <input id="otherTextbox" placeholder="Please describe here..." type="text" /><br />
    <br />
```

I'm not sure where to start. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need a JavaScript or jQuery component to make your form interactive.  I would state that in your question so that you generate the right interest for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on the earlier answer, I am guessing a bit at the .asp syntax, but you need to do something like the following.

You need to add some classes to you HTML, for example, `.radioButtonList` on your radio button group tag and `.otherItem` on the `<option>` tag corresponding to your other option.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" Class="radioButtonList" ... >
    <asp:ListItem Value="content1">Alumni...</asp:ListItem>
    ...
    <asp:ListItem Value="Content11">Photo/ Video of Past Events</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Content12" Class="otherItem">Other:</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Label ID="otherLabel" runat="server" 
    Text="If Other, please describe here: "></asp:Label>
<input id="otherTextbox" placeholder="Please describe here..." type="text" />
```

You then need to modify you jQuery selectors like this:

```
$('.radioButtonList .otherItem').click(function(){
    $('#otherLabel').show();
});
```

I have not tested this but it should be pretty close. This may need some adjustment if you have multiple radio button groups within the same form, please let me know if this is the case.

**Linking to jQuery**

You need to link to the jQuery framework file by adding a `<script>` tag in your head section, for example:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server"> 
    <link href="../includes/css/Intake.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.radioButtonList .otherItem').click(function(){
                $('#otherLabel').show();
            });
        });   
    </script> 
</asp:Content>
```

**Syntax Alert**

You may want to adjust your code and place the optional input field in the label tag:

```
<asp:Label ID="otherLabel" runat="server" Text="If Other... ">
    <input id="otherTextbox" placeholder="Please describe here..." type="text" />
</asp:Label>
```

otherwise you need to toggle both `.otherItem` and `#otherLabel`.

**jQuery for Multiple Radio Button Groups**

If you should happen to have multiple radio button groups within the same form needing the optional text input field, you would need to adjust the jQuery action.

One way of doing this is shown at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/TMkPX/

For example, if your HTML looked like this:

```
<ul class="radioGroup">
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="theOption2" value="Option1" />First Option</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="theOption2" value="Option2" />Second Option<label></li>
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="theOption2" value="Option3" />Third Option<label></li>
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="theOption2" value="OptionX" />Other Option<label></li>
    <li class="other"><input id="otherTextbox2" placeholder="Please describe here..." type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

the jQuery might look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.radioGroup input[value="OptionX"]').click(function () {
        $(this).parentsUntil('.radioGroup').nextAll('.other').show();
    });

    $('.radioGroup input[value!="OptionX"]').click(function () {
        $(this).parentsUntil('.radioGroup').nextAll('.other').hide();
    });
});
```

One action displays the hidden field as needed and the other hides it if the user changes his/her mind and picks an non-other option.

Comment: I do have multiple items. It's one single RadioButtonsList with about 10 items. 'Other' is the last item.

Comment: That is not a problem, the problem would be if you had several radio button groups, then click the "other" option on one would show all the other options in the other... easy enough to fix if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with jQuery

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/7GUqc/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input#radio').click(
        function(){
            $("#otherTextbox").show();
    });


});
```

Comment: If had additional radio buttons, and the user clicked pack to a standard option, then the extra input field should be hidden.  It would be easy enough to embellish your solution. (+1)

Comment: Works great in HTML... How would I implement this into asp.net though?

Comment: The HTML side works great. How would I implement this into asp.net?

Comment: asp.net is processed on the server, it does not interact with the user on a front end level, eg click events and so forth.

Comment: I understand it's processed on the server, but where would I place what you did, on this... <br />`<asp:ListItem Value="Content12">Other:</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:Label ID="otherLabel" runat="server" 
            Text="If Other, please describe here: "></asp:Label>
        <input id="otherTextbox" placeholder="Please describe here..." type="text" /><br />`

Comment: you would put it in the `<head>` of your HTML document.

Comment: You lost me... This site is a Web Site built in asp.net. There's no <head>. This is what the top of my Source looks like:  <br>`<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    <link href="../includes/css/Intake.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">`